Передача параметра в запрос из клиента к серверу (тонкий клиент УП)
Подскажите пожалуйста, Вызываю серверную функцию с клиента, передавая параметр. Ошибка: Не задано значение параметра
Запрос:
&НаСервере
Функция ЗапросДляФормированияФайла(КодСотрудника)
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
                Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
                               |    Сотрудники.Наименование КАК Наименование,
                               |    Сотрудники.Код КАК Код,
                               |    ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников.ДатаПриема КАК ДатаПриема,
                               |    ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников.ДатаУвольнения КАК ДатаУвольнения
                               |ИЗ
                               |    Справочник.Сотрудники КАК Сотрудники
                               |        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников КАК ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников
                               |        ПО (ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников.Сотрудник = Сотрудники.Ссылка)
                               |ГДЕ
                               |    Сотрудники.Код = &Код";
                Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("&Код", КодСотрудника);
                РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
                ТЗ1 = РезультатЗапроса.Выгрузить(); 
    Возврат ТЗ1;
КонецФункции

И подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я добавил результат запроса в ТаблицуЗначений?

При установке параметров нужно просто писать их имя, без знака "&":
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Код", КодСотрудника);


И подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я добавил результат запроса в ТаблицуЗначений?

Да. Можно вообще в одну строку:
ТЗ1 = Запрос.Выполнить().Выгрузить();

